# Proxy Resolver library in Rust

Tags: c++, c, proxy, rust

Currently, are there any stable proxy library written in Rust?

There are some alternatives in `Java` like [proxy-vole](https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/proxy-vole) which has the following abilities:

- Retrieve proxy `pac` script from any operating system(Could be gnome,kde,osx).
- Resolve the retrieved pac script

I currently could not found similar proxy resolver.

**First Question:** Are there any library there which has these abilities?

**Second Question:** If there is no library written in rust, are there any c/c++ library which has these abilities?

Comment: Please ask a separate question about C/C++, thanks! It will allow C/C++ experts to answer even if they do not know Rust. You can do that after the bounty is over, if you prefer.